# How to check whether a Java String contains GSM Extended Characters (non Unicode)

Tags: java, string, unicode, gsm

**My Aim:** I want to check whether a Java string contains characters from GSM Extended. The existing code successfully checks for GSM characters, but I am struggling to grasp how to check for GSM Extended characters such as '[' and ']'.

**My Code:**

```
private static final String GSM_EXTENDED = "\u000c^{}\\[~]|\u20ac";
public static boolean isUnicode(String input) {        
    return !((input.matches('[' + GSM + "]*")) || (input.matches('[' + GSM_EXTENDED + "]*")));
}
```

**Result:** My unit tests don't recognise ']' as GSM Extended, and furthermore, when any GSM Extended character is typed in from the GUI, they are not recognised as GSM.

Comment: Can't you use the unicode id like the others? \u005B and 
\u005D

Comment: Hi Djon. If I try making the GSM_EXTENDED String as "\u005B\u005D", then when my isUnicode() method runs I get ... Exception occurred in target VM: Unclosed character class near index 4
[[]]*

Comment: Ah! Maybe the String param of input.matches() needs the \ character to escape the bracket characters?

Comment: \\\u005B\\\u005D can be used for this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside square brackets in a regular expression, the hyphen is a special character, so you need to escape it as `"\\-"` in your GSM string.

The closing bracket ("]") in your GSM_EXTENDED string is terminating the bracketed character class, so you need to escape it as `"\\]"`.

Comment: Hi VGR. Ah yes, I think thats why ']' wasn't recognised in my unit test. However, GSM_EXTENDED characters are still not detected when typed into my GUI.

Comment: Ah, it was a combination of your answer, and that I had the logic of my isUnicode() method wrong. :)